# Xpath error - Imported content is empty

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am using ImportXML in Google Sheets to extract url provided for a Twitter profile.

My Xpath (that I got from Chrome Dev Tools) is:

```
//*[@id='page-container']/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/a/@title
```

I used similar Xpath to target, for example - the no. of followers for a given account and it worked fine but this one returns nothing.

I checked that path in Chrome dev tools and it returns me correct part of html but cannot extract the value....

I noticed that rel attribute on link is "me nofollow" - could that be a problem preventing from extracting value?

Comment: Can you post a sample xml of the twitter profile you're trying to import?

Comment: Is that what you're after @brent-d? That is the part of html I want to target and extract the value of the title attribute.

 <a class="u-textUserColor" target="_blank" rel="me nofollow" href="http://t.co/AkesnuuLgk" title="http://www.alti.co">
  alti.co
</a>

Comment: It's possible that the parent div structure is causing issues in the selectivity of your divs. Try getting all <a> tags that match: `//*[@id='page-container']//a[@rel='me nofollow']/@title`